# Is $p\wedge q\rightarrow p$ a valid argument?

Tags: logic

Those symbols represent the argument:

$p$: both rabbits and turtles are mammals

$c$: Rabbits are mammals.

On the one hand, I don't think it's an argument because it's a tautology, but on the other hand there's no way for $p$ to be false if $p\wedge q$ is true. Lastly, is it sound?

Comment: Turtles aren't mammals.

Comment: @Shaun, that's irrelevant for the logical structure of the argument.

Comment: @Shaun Ok? So what? We're talking about the argument's validity.

Comment: More to the point, though, it sounds like you think "tautology" and "valid argument" are mutually exclusive categories. Why would that be so?

Comment: @Troposphere If you define validity by inference, you could say that a tautology is invalid because there is no inference. Likewise how can an argument be valid if it's not an argument?

Comment: Yes it is. See [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination)

Comment: Does simplification apply when the conjunction is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be very pedantic, you could say that the symbols
$$ p \land q \to q $$
is not an *argument* at all, but just a *formula* (which as you mentioned happens to be a tautology). Since it's not an argument, asking whether it is a *valid* one is strictly speaking meaningless.

On the other hand,
$$ \text{From } p\land q\text{ we can conclude }q \qquad\qquad \Bigl(\textit{also written: }\frac{p\land q}{q}\Bigr)$$
is a valid *rule of inference*, and thus constitutes a valid *argument*, if "argument" means a meaningful combination of one or more rules of inference. (However, some authors use the convention that an *argument*, in contrast to an *inference*, is only called "valid" if the inferences in it are valid *and* the premises are true, which is not the case in your concrete example).

In many contexts, being as pedantic as this is unnecessary and uncalled for, though.

In particular, your tautological *formula* does become the *argument* you need if you combine it with the generic inference rule **modus ponens**.

---

This inference is still valid in situations where $p$ happens to be false. The design criterion for "valid" inferences is that *they must never let you conclude something false from premises that are true* -- on the other hand, what they allow us to conclude from *false* premises is harmless.

Comment: Troposphere? More like pedantsphere  (Kidding!)

Comment: @CameronWilliams: It's an attempt to guess at why the OP might think "tautology" is mutually exclusive from "valid argument"...

Comment: Yeah, just in good fun. I think this a good way to recast the logical statement as an actual argument to make it clear that it's really all the same and why we don't necessarily write things out the latter way even if it's perhaps a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "valid immediate inference, argument form and rule of inference". It's a regular use of [conjonction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination), one of the many [rules in propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus).

Comment: But what if p ^ q is not true?

Comment: Given that '$\rightarrow$' means a truth-functional symbol, the symbols at the header of the question are not an argument at all.  The other part though, seems more plausible as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You might have gotten tripped up by the use of 'argument' as meaning some sort of disagreed upon or some sort of contested proposition.  It doesn't always mean that, as a quick scan of a dictionary like Merriam Webster's reveals.

I would guess that an argument for your context is something like a series of propositions intended to establish the last proposition.  Something with truth-functional symbols, like ((p$\land$q)$\rightarrow$p) likely doesn't come as intended to establish anything, since what's the proposition it's trying to establish?  Simply put, it's a bunch of symbols with truth-functional variables and function symbols and there's no indication of it being anything else.  So, it seems that there's nothing it could get intended to establish.

A sound argument is one in which has only true premise(s) and only a true conclusion(s).